# How do I implement the MailSystem.NET components as references?

Tags: c#, mailsystem.net

I need to use the ActiveUp.Net.Mail namespace, and I tried to add it but I am not able to find any DLL files in the MailSystem.NET archive/folder and I just 
recently started working with C# so is there something that I'm missing?

Downloaded from https://github.com/pmengal/MailSystem.NET , in the Class/ActiveUp. exist all the namespaces which I need but as folders, and I have no where near a DLL file, so I'm pretty stuck!

Comment: You need to build the source code to an assembly. Use a development environment like Visual Studio for that.

Comment: Or just [install from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailSystem.NET/). If you're using Visual Studio then there's the NuGet package manager built into all recent versions. (Actually, that looks out of date :-/ )

Answer (score 0):

**Unblocking**

First after downloading the archive file you have to unblock it, to unblock it you need to go to the properties of the file and check unblock on the security row at the bottom of the window, then click apply, and now the file is unblocked.

This part is based on @dymanoid

**Compiling**

After you extract the file, on the root of the main folder is a Visual Studio Solution (.sln) file which you need to run and compile.
After compiling, the .DLL files which are needed to be passed as references are found on the Class-Library/Bin folder.